# Is there any good iCal & vCal parser in php(library)?

Tags: php, icalendar, vcalendar, vcal

I'm creating a web app that need to upload iCal or vCal files. I wonder if there is any php library that can parse the information, so I can store it on my database?

Comment: is this is what you looking for?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782534/icalendar-parser-in-php-that-supports-timezones

Comment: it needs to support vCalendar files too. so no.

Answer (score -1):

that should help 
http://www.phpbuilder.com/columns/chow20021007.php3?print_mode=1

Answer (score -1):

This seems the most complete and updated.
http://kigkonsult.se/index.php

It goes from parsing to generation of .ics files