# ISO Datetime in PHP

Tags: php, datetime, timezone, icalendar, rfc5545

I have an ISO DATETIME format parsed from web calendar ICS files. I have created calendar event in google and yahoo. In google, I have created for the time of 11:00 to 11:30 IST.
In yahoo, I have created for the time of 11:30 to 11:45 IST.

I have received ICS files for both the events. My problem is with the event start time and end time in the ICS files.

Google Start time - 20140218T060000Z (provides GMT time)

Yahoo Start time - 20140218T113000Z (provides local time)

How can I check if the timezone in the ISO datetime is GMT and convert it to GMT if not? Please help me to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's impossible to tell because both time zones are Z(ulu) aka GMT, according to their string representation.

Comment: @Jack SO mentions that those dates have been parsed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a timezone declaration in the ical file you can use.

[The RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.2.19) places this on the `DTSTART`, for example:

```
DTSTART;TZID=America/New_York:19980119T020000
```

But ical is not a very exact "science", it seems like everybody uses it different. I've seen timezone declarations like this:

```
X-WR-TIMEZONE:Europe/Berlin
```

which only show up once in the ical file.

After creating a DateTime object you can use DateTime::setTimezone to set it. Example from the [PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/de/datetime.settimezone.php):

```
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01', new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Nauru'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";

$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Chatham'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

As Gerald indicates the difference comes from the fact that the `DTSTART` (and by the way also the `DTEND`) properties of your event are referenced either explicitly (as per [RFC 5545 - time zone identifier](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.2.19)) or implicitely via `X-WR-TIMEZONE` (Apple iCal).

In the first case you have to handle the `VTIMEZONE` component ([RFC5545 - VTIMEZONE component)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.6.5). For which you will need an [ICalendar parser in PHP that supports timezones](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1782534/1167333)

In the second case you have to refer to the [Olson database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database#Usage_and_extensions), and may need to use [timezonedb](http://pecl.php.net/package/timezonedb) instead of the default php one.

However you should probably read this [blog](http://blog.jonudell.net/2011/10/17/x-wr-timezone-considered-harmful/) entry from J. Dunnell on possible pitfalls of dealing with `X-WR-TIMEZONE` before getting started on this journey...

Answer (score -1):

you can use the `date` and `strtotime` functions in php.

say

```
  // apply this to all your times
  $start_time = "20140218T060000Z";
  $timeZone = date("e",strtotime($start_time));

  if($timeZone != "UTC"){ // UTC is same as GMT in case you're wondering
      $start_time_gmt = gmdate("Ymd\THis\Z",$start_time); // the \T an \Z are key characters for the date function so you need to escape them if you want to display it in that format
  }
```

References:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

http://php.net/strtotime