# Good way to get rid of / deal with timezones in a ical file?

Tags: php, timezone, icalendar, rfc5545

I am trying to get my calendar from a groupware-server (ics file) parsed using php. So far so good except for the possibility to define additional timezones per ical event entry:

```
DTSTART;TZID="Amsterdam, Belgrade, Berlin, Brussels, Budapest, Madrid, Paris, Prague, Stockholm":20110723T193000
DTEND;TZID="Amsterdam, Belgrade, Berlin, Brussels, Budapest, Madrid, Paris, Prague, Stockholm":20110724T000000
```

Another event is i.e. in

```
DTSTART;TZID="Greenland (Danmarkshavn)":20120523T193000
DTEND;TZID="Greenland (Danmarkshavn)":20120524T000000
```

The problem is that the common parser classes found online just strip those TZID parameter which results in moving the event to the timestamp at the end of the string.

Is there any parser for php taking care of that issue?

Comment: Just dropped the timezones completely and converted by hand. fed up with no proper solution that worked. Thanks guys for trying at least!

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer:

[sabre/vobject](http://sabre.io/vobject/) has a pretty extensive list of timezone mappings like this, to map to their olson counterparts. Full list [here](https://github.com/fruux/sabre-vobject/tree/master/lib/Sabre/VObject/timezonedata).

But it doesn't look like the specific strings you've found are in that.

iCalendar objects that are standards compliant should actually also contain a `VTIMEZONE` object, above the VEVENT object. The information in the `VTIMEZONE` object helps parsers such as vobject figure out what the intended timezone was.

If you don't see `VTIMEZONE` anywhere in the source, it means that the groupware server you're using is producing broken iCalendar files. I'd recommend filing a bug suggesting this. There's many applications that produce iCalendar that do not include `VTIMEZONE`, but these applications tend to use the Olson identifier (such as `Europe/Amsterdam`) which is very widely supported.

Comment: Well, those cities are all in the same timezone. So the id is quite funky but I dont think there is any problem with it (as long as there is a corresponding VTIMEZONE with the same funky id).

Comment: @arnaudq: For some reason I thought prague was one hour to the right :( I'm dumb

Answer (score -1):

you should have a look at:  http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/16660.html

according to this thread it handles TZID: [ICalendar parser in PHP that supports timezones](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1782534)